# Find text node after a node with XPath

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I am trying to use `document.evaluate` to find text nodes matching my query. The issue I found is that with the XPath I am using, it is not finding text nodes that follow another element. For example, given these conditions ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/sy0LLfqw/)):

HTML

```
<div><p>$100</p></div>
<p>Test test <span>test</span> $100 test</p>
```

Javascript

```
var item,
  indx = 0,
  items = document.evaluate('//*[contains(text(),"$")]', document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

while (item = items.snapshotItem(indx++)) {
  if (item.nodeName !== 'SCRIPT') {
    console.log(item.textContent);
  }
}
```

This XPath only finds the first `$`, the second isn't found because of the `<span>` in the middle.

So my question is how can I change the javascript (not the HTML) to find both matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the XPath expression to `//*[text()[contains(.,"$")]]` as that selects elements having a text child node containing the `$` symbol.

Comment: I tried that change in the fiddle I shared, and I'm seeing this error: `not a valid XPath expression`

Comment: I tried `'*[contains(.,"$")]'` and that did find both elements, *but* if you use `document`, it returns the `html` element, and switching to `document.body` returns the outermost wrapper, which is not optimal.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a closing `]`, now edited and corrected.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much!